# JAXB - unmarshal doesn't work

Tags: java, javafx, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have small problem with unmarshaller. Let's take a look at this method:

```
public void loadProductDataFromFile (File file) {
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ProductListWrapper.class);
        Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
        ProductListWrapper wrapper = (ProductListWrapper) um.unmarshal(file);   // this always cause exception

        products.clear();
        products.addAll(wrapper.getProducts());

        setProductFilePath(file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("Fail!");
        alert.setHeaderText("Can't read data!");
        alert.setContentText("Can't read data from:\n" + file.getPath() );
        alert.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

and this is my ProductListWrapper:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "products")
public class ProductListWrapper {
    private List<Product> products;

    @XmlElement(name = "products")
    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        this.products=products;
    }
}
```

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<products>
     <products>
           <amount>124</amount>
           <ifConttainsPreservatives>false</ifConttainsPreservatives>
           <name>Apple</name>
           <type>FRUITS</type>
     </products>
</products>
```

And my method for saving from my ObservableList (that works I think):

```
 public void saveProductsDataToFile(File file) {
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ProductListWrapper.class);
            Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            ProductListWrapper wrapper = new ProductListWrapper();
            wrapper.setProducts(products);
            m.marshal(wrapper, file);
            setProductFilePath(file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Fail!");
            alert.setHeaderText("Can't save data!");
            alert.setContentText("Can't save data to:\n" + file.getPath() );
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
```

My Product.class:

```
public class Product {
    private StringProperty name;
    private IntegerProperty amount;
    private ProductType type;
    private BooleanProperty ifConttainsPreservatives;

    public void setType(ProductType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public boolean isIfConttainsPreservatives() {
        return ifConttainsPreservatives.get();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount.set(amount);
    }

    public void setIfConttainsPreservatives(boolean ifConttainsPreservatives) {
        this.ifConttainsPreservatives.set(ifConttainsPreservatives);
    }

    public ProductType getType() {

        return type;
    }

    public BooleanProperty ifConttainsPreservativesProperty() {
        return ifConttainsPreservatives;
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty amountProperty() {
        return amount;
    }

    public Product(int amount, boolean ifContainsPreservatives, String name, ProductType type) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.amount = new SimpleIntegerProperty(amount);
        this.ifConttainsPreservatives = new SimpleBooleanProperty(ifContainsPreservatives);
        this.type =type;
    }

    public Product() {
    }
}
```

Types are IntegerProperty, ProductType (enum), StringProperty and BooleanProperty. What is wrong? Can somebody help me?

Comment: And what means `doesn't work`?

Comment: Always unmarhall cause Exception and doesn't load to ObservableList from XML.

Comment: Then add the stacktrace to your  question

Comment: What Exception? And, please take a closer look at your XML. There is an unexpected dash (`-`). Is it present in your file or is it a typo?

Comment: You will also get a lot of `NullPointerException`s if you feed your program the right input because your `XXXProperty`s in `Product` class is not initialized. Both unmarshaller and marshaller should stuck in the setter/gett of that class.

Comment: Sorry about XML file, I copied that from IE (which adds dash (-) so I can show and hide some parts of code). I've opened it in Wordpad and it's without dashes.
About Exception. I can't see which one but always show me alert window.

Comment: I've tried do this from: http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part5/

Comment: Shouldn't each product have an enveloping `<product>...</product>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

1. The xml file is invalid. `standalone` should have a value of `yes` instead of `true`.
2. You do not create the properties of `Product` in the constructor without parameters that jaxb will use.

You need to do some changes:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<products>
     <products>
           <amount>124</amount>
           <ifConttainsPreservatives>false</ifConttainsPreservatives>
           <name>Apple</name>
           <type>FRUITS</type>
     </products>
</products>
```

```
public class Product {
    ...

    public Product() {
        // invoke constructor that does assign the properties
        this(0, false, null, null);
    }
}
```

---

Note that it's a good idea to make the property fields final to make the compiler complain, if such fields are not initialized/reassigned:

```
private final StringProperty name;
private final IntegerProperty amount;
private ProductType type;
private final BooleanProperty ifConttainsPreservatives;
```